# Mapping slug with database entry

Tags: php, symfony, routes, slug

In a symfony project, I have a url pattern like this

```
/resource/{id}
```

I can convert this to a sluggified url as

```
/resource/{slug}
```

using documentation given in [symfony webiste](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html).

But, I don't know further how to map this `{slug}` to a record in database. Is there any standard way to do this other than creating a `slug` variable in entity class and storing one in database then retrieving record using that property?

**UPDATE**

I don't know how symfony is retrieving data from database. My view action is as follows.

```
 /**
 * Finds and displays a Resource entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{slug}", name="resource_show")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function showAction(Resource $resource)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($resource);
    return $this->render('resource/show.html.twig', array(
        'resource' => $resource,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

I just replaced `id` with `slug` in controller after making proper modifications in `ResourceEntity`. Now symfony is automatically retrieving information from database using `slug` and it is passed to `showAction` method..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have mentioned is correct,
you should generate a Unique Slug from a String ( Ex: Post Title ) , store it in the DB, and find the Entity by Slug

Example :

```
$obj = $repository->findOneBySlug('test-post');
```

if you want to make the process of creating Slug easy and using well tested library , you can use [Sluggable behavior extension for Doctrine.](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sluggable.md)

Comment: What is `findBySlug` in your code segment? Is it something auto generated by symfony? Or a custom method to be created?

Comment: @niyasc Doctrine provides findOneBy*() findBy*()  where you can replace the * with a valid property ( column name )

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is to use Synmfony ParameterConvereter.

Here it is how it shold look like:

Lets say you have a `User` entity. Pay attention to `slug` field.

```
/**
 * Class User
 *
 * @package AppBundle\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Gedmo\Loggable
 */
class User extends BaseUser implements Translatable
{
    /**
     * @var $id
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     * @ORM\Column(type="guid")
     *
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @Gedmo\Versioned
     * @ORM\Column(type="string"))
     */
    protected $username;
    /**
     * @var
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string"))
     */
    protected $firstName;

    /**
     * @var
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string"))
     */
    protected $lastName;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"firstName"}, style="camel", updatable=false, separator="-")
     * @ORM\Column(length=128, unique=true)
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Locale
     * Used locale to override Translation listener`s locale
     * this is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property
     */
    private $locale;

// ...
```

So in route in stead of having id, you will have user's first name.

Then in controller all you have to do is this:

```
    /**
     * @param User    $user
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return array
     *
     * @Route(path="/edit/{slug}", name="trans_edit")
     * @ParamConverter("user", class="AppBundle:User", options={"slug" = "slug"})

     * @Template()
     */
    public function editAction(User $user, Request $request)
    {
        dump($user);
    }

// ...
```

Slug in automatically converted into `User` object. No need to manually call DB, ParameterConvereter will do it for you automatically.